# Angular 13 Cannot get rid of Object is possible null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

I have some code that contains this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("div0");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element); // Error points here
```

I keep getting:

`object is possibly 'null'` and tried added ! to element but it still complains.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: This is typescript error. 
You should to update tsconfig to disable check for null, or as an alternative change the following: 
let element: any = document.getElementById("div0");

and please, don't use var, its deprecated.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Sh. Pavel it is a Typescript error.

From my point of view you have several options but I just point out two options, which I think are the best for your issue.

**Option 1: Optional Chaining**

By using [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) the code stops the execution if it runs into a `null` or `undefined`. Also, it produces cleaner and less code than adding a guard for each potentially nullable property.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("div0");
element?.parentNode?.removeChild(element);
```

**Option 2: Guard**

By using a guard the code part can only be reached if the condition is true, so Typescript understand that the values are defined then

```js
const element = document.getElementById("div0");
if (element && element.parentNode) {
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an error thrown by typescript, because the return type of `document.getElementById` is `HTMLElement | null`. You could disable this check by setting `strictNullChecks: false` in your tsconfig, however this is a helpful check, since the call might actually return null if the element does not exist in the DOM. You have other options to deal with this without disabling the check.

You could check for `null` and handle the case:

```
const element = document.getElementById('div0');
if (element === null) {
  // you should handle the case in an appropriate way here
  throw new Error('Element "div0" does not exist.');
}

// after the check above, the error will not be thrown anymore
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

You could use the `!` operator to tell typescript that it should assume the value will never be null:

```
const element = document.getElementById('div0')!;
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Note that this approach will lead to a runtime error if `element` is `null` during runtime.

Or you could use the `?` to only call `removeChild` if element is not `null`:

```
const element = document.getElementById('div0');
element?.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

This will only access `parentNode` on `element` if element is not null. Otherwise the expression will evaluate to `null` and `removeChild` is not called.